ExecutorLostFailure (executor 3 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Command exited with code 52
Here my system configuration info:

Nodes : 32
Ram   : 32Gb
Cores : 18

My spark standalone configuration are:

Driver memory   : 5g
Executor memory : 6G
Executor cores  : 3

I tried to train the pyspark ML model using spark-submit train.py . but fails to code 52
I tried various formation, according to previous solution but not working . after 3 epochs I got this error
ERROR Instrumentation: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 11 in stage 15.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 11.3 in stage 15.0 (TID 254) (172.20.214.214 executor 3): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 3 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Command exited with code 52
